# RSQLite: Read Blob from MBTiles files

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite, mbtiles

I have an MBTiles file, which I can read with RSQLite like so:

```
> dbGetQuery(con, "select * from tiles limit 10")
   zoom_level tile_column tile_row       tile_data
1           8          40      156  blob[26.45 kB]
2           8          40      159 blob[115.86 kB]
3           8          40      157 blob[134.76 kB]
4           8          41      159 blob[129.18 kB]
5           8          69      163     blob[220 B]
6           8           5      171     blob[385 B]
7           8          41      158 blob[152.95 kB]
8           8          40      158 blob[150.38 kB]
9           8          68      160 blob[148.55 kB]
10          8          69      162  blob[18.19 kB]
```

I need to retrieve the feature IDs of each xyz combination, which lies in the `tile_data` column. `sf` can read MBTiles files with GDAL, but it doesn't return the tile routing path, and I don't need the geometric component in any case.

As it is now, each `blob` component is a raw vector that I don't know how to process, and querying quote(tile_data) doesn't seem to help either.

Thank you!